# parsing String in swift

Tags: swift, string, parsing

Which is the best method to parse the following string to read name and roll number

```
"Student"={"Info"={}},
"Student"={"SchoolName"="abc","place"="abc","Info"={"Name"="student1","class"="class1"}},
"Student"={"SchoolName"="abc","place"="bbc,"Info"={"Name"="student2","class"="class1"}}
```

is it possible to parse this string directly to an array of dictionary?

Comment: It can be quite easily converted to JSON by replacing some characters if there is a double quote after  `"bbc`. If not it's pretty hard to do that.

Comment: yes, there is a double quote after bbl also

Answer (score 2):

If this was a json things could have been lot more easier. Since this is a string I don't see a way other than using a regex pattern.

```
let string = """
"Student"={"Info":{}},
"Student"={"SchoolName":"abc","place":"abc","Info":{"Name":"student1","class":"class1"}},
"Student"={"SchoolName":"abc","place":"bbc","Info":{"Name":"student2","class":"class1"}}
"""

let pattern = #"Name":"([^"]+)","class":"([^"]+)""#

var array: [[String: String]] = []

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

regex.enumerateMatches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count)) { match, _, _ in
    if let match = match {
        
        let nameRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!
        let classRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!
        
        let name = String(string[nameRange])
        let classValue = String(string[classRange])
        
        array.append(["Name": name, "RollNumber": classValue])
    }
}
```

```
//output
print(array) //[["Name": "student1", "RollNumber": "class1"], ["Name": "student2", "RollNumber": "class1"]]

print(array[0]["Name"]) //Optional("student1")
print(array[0]["RollNumber"]) //Optional("class1")
```

FYI : if this is a part of a JSON decode it as a json. do not try to decode as a string.

Answer (score 2):

If it's guaranteed that all keys are wrapped in double quotes you can convert the string to valid JSON by replacing the `=` characters with `:` and adding the missing braces and brackets.

```
var string = """
"Student"={"Info"={}},
"Student"={"SchoolName"="abc","place"="abc","Info"={"Name"="student1","class"="class1"}},
"Student"={"SchoolName"="abc","place"="bbc","Info"={"Name"="student2","class"="class1"}}
"""

string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: ":")
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"Student", with: "{\"Student")
string = "[" + string.replacingOccurrences(of: "},", with: "}},") + "}]"
```

The matching structs are

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case student = "Student"}
    
    let student: Student?
}

struct Student : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case schoolName = "SchoolName", place, info = "Info" }

    let schoolName: String?
    let place: String?
    let info: Info
}

struct Info : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name = "Name", className = "class" }  

    let name: String?
    let className: String?
}
```

and you can decode and display the data with

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: Data(string.utf8))
    for item in result where item.student?.info.name != nil {
        let info = item.student!.info
        print("Name", info.name!, "Class", info.className ?? "No class available")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```